# garchFit error: Error in solve.default(fit$hessian) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 9.58802e-18

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm using R to fit a AR-GARCH model and got the following error. Is there a way to resolve it?

```
fit1=garchFit(~ arma(1,0)+garch(2,1), data = M1[,1], cond.dist = "sstd", trace = FALSE)
Error in solve.default(fit$hessian) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 9.58802e-18
```